# Setting on image overlay onto navigation?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

apologies if this question seems odd but I wasn't quite sure how to word this as I am new to web development. So I am going to post a screen shot of what I am trying to accomplish.[image: Image of how I want the navigation to look.] So at this point I have the logo name, navigation links, registration buttons, heading title and the start for free/learn more buttons all done. I also have the gradient background complete. If you look closely, I need to add an image that is the same color of the gradient background to the nav. [image: the image I need to add] As you can see the image is definitely zoomed in, and most of it seems to get cut out. I have no clue how to accomplish this task or what tool to use. Any help I can get on how to do this would be appreciated as I have been stuck on this for while. Again apologies for the wording and if this has been asked already but honestly I dont know where to look for solutions, thanks.

Comment: Can you share the website link

Comment: You can do that using css / give the second img style `overflow: hidden;` and the width + height you want + your positive and give  the first img `z-indez:-1`

Answer (score 0):

If am not wrong, I believe.. you are trying to fit the image without zooming in. This might be of some help to you.

```
#img.source-image {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```